# Multiple hotkeys for the same function

Tags: shortcut

I'm trying to get a single function mapped to multiple hotkeys.

Specifically, I want to rotate the 3d view by holding shift+middle mouse button or the * key on the num key. (Pan has been moved to middle mouse)

Either solution works independently, but I have a problem that if I use the knife tool with * (my preferred solution because I cannot make a macro to press shift+middle mouse on my mouse) it will not rotate, so I would like in that instance to be able to press shift plus middle mouse even though normally I would like ot press *.

I see multiple "View3D.rotate" I can change the hotkey of, but only the first actually works.

Any advice? (Even telling me how to Macro my Naga mouse would be helpful ahah)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1. At the bottom of the 3D View input list, click on the "Add New" Button. A new command will then appear at the bottom of the listed named "None".
2. Click on the triangle to the left of the word "None" to expand the options for the command. Enter this text: **view3d.rotate** (as shown in the image below) and press Enter. At this point the name of the command will change from "None" to "Rotate View" and you can choose you input command.

You may also want to double check that the command is not already in use by searching for it in the "Key Bindings" search box at the top of the list. If it is in use you can just disable it by clicking on the checkmark next to its name. That way you won't have any conflicts... hopefully.

Comment: Thanks, it's worth noting though that I had to type view3d.rotate and not view.3d.rotate.

Comment: My apologies for the typo. I'm glad I added the image as a backup. Thanks for letting me know so I can fix that.

Comment: I want to assign the Shift+3 for the visibility of the cutter folder on Blender 2.90 but it's not working for me! Can anybody tell me how to assign that?

Comment: Is it possible to map 1 hotkey to do 2 things?    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215761/ctrls-doesnt-save-modified-textures-lost-hours-of-work