# 'Ctrl+S' doesn't save modified textures ==> lost hours of work

Tags: image, shortcut, packed-data

My Blender daily life is :-

1. Create a texture
2. Pack it
3. Save (<kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>)
4. Edit the texture
5. Save (<kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>)
6. Blender crashes  ===> I lose all work in Step 4.
   (This can also be tested by terminating the Blender process.)

How to make <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> saves **BOTH** the dot-blend file **AND** all of the modified  ***packed*** images?
In preference, the command to do so is `image.save_all_modified`.

**My current workarounds**

1. Create another hotkey for `image.save_all_modified`.  To save properly,  press both <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> and another one. I have to press the new hotkey   with the mouse hover within the "Image Editor" workpane before <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>.
2. Enabling `File > External Data > Automatically Pack Into .blend` will pack all images , including unwanted big external image.
3. (best so far) Whenever I want to save properly, I close the program.  Blender will popup whether I want to save modified image(s).  I answer yes.   After that, I re-open my file again.

**Related issue** : https://developer.blender.org/T45636

**After get brockmann's awesome answer** :  If anyone want to extend the script and check whether an image is packed, it can be read at [Detect with python script if a blend file has packed images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93412/detect-with-python-script-if-a-blend-file-is-packed-with-images).   Adding these code in `save_mod_images()` can be useful.  It will reload all external files, so now the script will save & sync (reload external) in one go :-

```
for i in bpy.data.images:
    if i.packed_file is None :
        i.reload()
```

Comment: Reloading the images before *closing* the file doesn't make any sense to me (at a first glance) because the images are going to be reloaded when opening the file anyway, aren't they?

Comment: @brockmann :: My workflow is :: edit internal texture OR external texture OR model --> `Ctrl+S`  to backup & sync --> continue editing  .  I don't close the file yet. Is it weird? ^^'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [**application handlers**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#module-bpy.app.handlers), specifically [`save_pre`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#bpy.app.handlers.save_pre) handler. When you're saving the file, the handler kicks in and allows to execute whatever you want *before* saving the file.

The following demo *saves all modified images* when you are hitting save, automatically:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def save_mod_images(dummy):
    """ Save all modified images """
    if any(i.is_dirty for i in bpy.data.images):
        bpy.ops.image.save_all_modified()

@persistent
def pack_dirty_images(dummy):
    """ Pack all modified images """ 
    for i in bpy.data.images:
        if i.is_dirty:
            i.pack()
            print("Packed:", i.name)
            
bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(save_mod_images)
#bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(pack_dirty_images)
```

**Copy-paste the script into the text editor and run it using the play button,** this is going to add the handler to the current Blender session. If you'd like to *pack all unsaved images when saving the file*, just un-comment `bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(pack_dirty_images)`.

---

#### `image-data-linter.py`

For simplicity, this can be easily turned into an **Add-on**. Add the usual [`bl_info` dict](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html?highlight=bl_info#addonpreferences-bpy-struct), `register` and `unregister` functions and make sure to `remove` the handler when the add-on gets un-registered, further reading: [**How to create a custom UI?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)

[image]
*Added both options to the Add-on preferences so they can be easily turned on or off.*

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

bl_info = {
    "name": "Image Data Linter",
    "description": "Save or pack all modified images when saving the file",
    "author": "brockmann",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "",
    "category": "Development"
}

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


class ImageDataLinterPrefs(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):

    bl_idname = __name__

    save: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Save modified Images",
        description="Save modified images when saving the blend",
        default=True)

    pack: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Pack un-saved Images",
        description="Pack un-saved images when saving the blend",
        default=False)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "save", toggle=True, icon="DISK_DRIVE")
        layout.prop(self, "pack", toggle=True, icon="PACKAGE")
        layout.separator()


@persistent
def pack_dirty_images(dummy):
    if bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.pack:
        for i in bpy.data.images:
            if i.is_dirty:
                i.pack()
                print("Packed:", i.name)

@persistent
def save_mod_images(dummy):
    if bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.save:
        """ Save all modified images """
        if any(i.is_dirty for i in bpy.data.images):
            bpy.ops.image.save_all_modified()


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ImageDataLinterPrefs)
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(save_mod_images)
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(pack_dirty_images)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.remove(pack_dirty_images)
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.remove(save_mod_images)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ImageDataLinterPrefs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Save the script as `image-data-linter.py`, go to the *User Preferences > Add-ons > Install*. Further reading: [**How to install an Add-on**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon/1689)