# Painted textures not visible anymore

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

So I created some objects, UV unwrapped and projected them, painted on their textures and everything seemed fine. They were rendering and everything. I closed blender, and then re-opened it. However now, the textures I painted only show on the objects as black now! Although I can see the textures I painted in the tiny thumbnails in the images within UV editor, when I click on them they show up completely black as well! Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you saved the image files? Images are external data and must be saved additionally if they are not packed into the blend file. The image files don't get saved automatically when you save the blend file. If you quit Blender it usually warns you that there are unsaved images and offers you to save them. That's fine but when Blender crashes the image data is lost.

Comment: Related question: ['Ctrl+S' doesn't save modified textures ==> lost hours of work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/215761/107598)