# Multiple Function Accelerator Hotkeys

Tags: python, add-on, keymap

Is it possible to have a multiple letter hotkey while simultaneously having a multiple function activated within Blender? For instance, say I want the letter **a** to activate something, and then the letter **b** to do something else. So, you would hold down the "**a**" key, and then tap the "**b**" key to do that something else. This is sort of the case with say, Shift, CTRL etc that you can add to a hotkey within the keymap editor, but not exactly. There is a blank option to put in a 2nd letter (to the right of the Cmd button). My initial attempt was to map that 2nd letter to something else with the "Add New" feature, but this deactivates the first function from the double lettered (**a** + **b**) hotkey.
[image]

So what would be a use case for this? Hold down "**a**" to go into Edit Mode, and then tap "**b**" to select all vertices. Or, while still holding down "**a**", you decide you'd rather have all edges selected, so tap "**c**" to grab all edges (**a**,**b** and **c** being example hotkeys, not necessarily what I'd be using). Etc. Problem is it's sort of like having two hotkeys in one. I suppose it would be something akin to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33388/multiple-hotkeys-for-the-same-function) but would be worded "Multiple functions for the same hotkey" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for a custom Pie Menu. Pie Menus can have accelerator keys. You press and hold a key to open the Pie Menu, then you can press one of a few key options to trigger the corresponding operator (or move your mouse to the operator).

[image: Pie Menu]

Comment: That's definitely close to what I'm looking for, although I don't need the pie menu to show up

Comment: This could do as a workaround, if only I could get the accelerator keys in the pie menu to be letters instead of numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: There are both letters and numbers. The underlined letters are accelerator keys. They would trigger the operator just like the numbers shown on the right would.